# Dispaly image from database through servlet on jsp

Tags: java, image, servlets

I am unable to display my image from the database onto my jsp page and I still cannot get where the problem is please help.

My servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        Connection conn;
         try {
             conn =  db.getDbConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select stu_image from student_images_table where STU_REG_NO = ?");
            String id = request.getParameter("studentregno");
            ps.setString(1,id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            Blob  b = rs.getBlob("stu_image");            
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            response.setContentLength( (int) b.length());
           // response.setContentLength(10);
            InputStream is = b.getBinaryStream();
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            byte buf[] = new byte[(int) b.length()];
            is.read(buf);
            os.write(buf);
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My JSP:

```
<div id="bv_Image1" style="margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;left:572px;top:31px;width:194px;height:162px;text-align:left;z-index:1;">
                        <img src="ProfileInquiryServlet" id="Image1" alt="" align="top" border="0" style="width:194px;height:162px;"></div>
```

My Display:

[image: My Display has no Image]

What could I be doing Wrong?

**EDIT:**
My Web.xml is huge but maybe this might be relevant;

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProfileInquiryServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.kollega.controller.ProfileInquiryServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProfileInquiryServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ProfileInquiryServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is your JSP running in same servlet context path?

Comment: I do not get :P I am kind of new to this.

Comment: How you mapped img tag in html to servlet?

Comment: ` request.getRequestDispatcher("/studentprofile.jsp").forward(request, response);` :P

Comment: `response.setContentLength(10);` maybe? I think `os.flush()` should be done instead of `os.close()`. And use `<img width="194" ...>`

Comment: post your web.xml code.

Comment: See the edit I posted.

Comment: To debug your code first type 'http://localhost:8080/webcontext/ProfileInquiryServlet' make send us the exception? is it exception or not found ?!

Comment: The return value of `is.read(buf)` tells you whether the buffer was actually filled.  If you don't check it, sooner or later there will come a time when `buf` doesn't contain all of your image data.  One easy solution to this is to wrap the InputStream in a DataInputStream and call its [`readFully`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte[]%29) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one servlet for the image, and pass it the `studentregno`:

```
<img src="ProfileInquiryServlet?studentregno=${param.studentregno}" ...
```

This is a separate request, and hence need to have that parameter.

---

The first servlet can do `request.setAttribute("regno", "...");` and then in the JSP you can use `${regno}`. The `request.getParameter("studentregno")` is available as `${param.studentregno}`.

Comment: I am sorry I do not get you. May be I should say I am a beginners in servlets.

Comment: Thank I just Moved this code to another servlet a separate one and passed regno parameter through the session and the Image Appeared.

Comment: You should better pass it through the request.